# How to prevent download file when print by print-html-element npm library?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, electron

I am developing a desktop app with electron node.js and use a library print-html-element for the print HTML page. The printing HTML was processed correctly but with this, after selecting the printer(Microsoft XPS document writer) give me a download(Save Print Output As) XPS file option. But I don't want to open this option, I want to disable or prevent the download.
Below is the code which is I was used in my project

var PHE = require("print-html-element");
PHE.printElement( document.getElementById('invoice'));

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vAkkZ.png)

Comment: I very much doubt that is under your control. My system decides how my print drivers behave, not any random website.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/download-item.
If you have a single window application, try the below code in your main js.

```
const { BrowserWindow } = require('electron')
let win = new BrowserWindow();//use your window that trigger the download
win.webContents.session.on('will-download', (event, item, webContents) => {
//disable downloading the file
  event.preventDefault();
})
```